# Static libray Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new in c++, and I want to use a static library of tensorflow lite to load and run a model of tensorflow on a c++ program. But after I built the library and run the program ( with the library.a include inside), there is a problem :

```
./libtensorflow-lite.a:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id
!<arch>
^
./libtensorflow-lite.a:2:3: error: invalid filename for line marker directive
#1/20           1595980892  0     0     100644  664268    `
  ^
[....]
```

If you could give me a clue of how to import this library with no errors it's would be awesome.

PS: I built the library with ./build_lib.sh which is on the git of tensorflow at the address tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/build_lib.sh

Comment: Elaborate the issue with what you have tried, show your code snippet.

Comment: i just try to import the library in my code with: #include "libtensorflow-lite.a" . The static library is in the same folder than my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load and run a TFLite model in C++, use the [TFLite C++ Inference API](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_c)